# Could someone explain how this piece of Python code works? (sorted list with lambda function)

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I was trying to sort a list of lists on the second item in each of the lists in my "unsorted list", and found this piece of code. It works, but even though I have read about lambda function I'm having some problems wrapping my head around how it works. Could someone explain how it works, and maybe give me some input if this is a good way of sorting a list of lists or if i should use a different approach. In advance, thanks!

```
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list,key=lambda l:l[1])
```

Comment: Can you paste the value of unsorted_list to explain you better, BTW you can also refer to this link http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php which will help you with the basics

Comment: The unsorted_list is something like this:
unsorted_list = [[item_two, 2], [item_one, 1], [item_three, 3]]
The goal was to sort the list of lists by the value at index 1 like this:
sorted_list = [[item_one, 1], [item_two, 2], [item_three, 3]]

Comment: So sorted has this option to sort via the key. So "lambda l:l[1])" says for each array in l get the first index of that particular array. In your case it will sort with 2,1,3 which is nothing but the first index of each array. This values are given to sorted's key parameter and thats how the listing is done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize the language, but it seems that the code is sorting an array of arrays, using the element at index 1 as the sorting key.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to define the language. The language is Python. :)